# Using class member as a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to tell `Typescript` that one member of one of my `class` is coming from another `class`.
For example:

```
Class Main{
  getDataFromChild(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
}

Class Child{
  getDataFromChild: Main.getDataFromChild //<== something like this
}
```

---

**Use Case**

My use case is `React` parent passing method down to `React` child. I want my IDE to navigate to Parent method decleration when I click on the passed method inside child.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {


  simplifiedFunction (value) { // Line A
    console.log(value)
  }

  render () {
  return (
    <div>
    <Child
          simplifiedFunction = {this.simplifiedFunction} 
        />
    </div>
    )
  }

}

export default class Child extends Component {

  render () {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1 onClick= { () =>
            this.props.simplifiedFunction(<SomethingThatYouWantToPassIn>)//<== ctrl + click on simplifiedFunction should take me to its definition in parent class (Line A)
          }
        > Something</h1>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface (named or anonymous):

```
interface SharedFeature {
  sharedFunction: () => void;
}
```

and then implement it on the parent

```
class Parent extends React.Component implements SharedFeature {
  sharedFunction() { ... }
  render() { return <Child sharedFunction={sharedFunction} />; }
}
```

finally you can use the interface as part of the Child component's props

```
class Child extends React.Component<SharedFeature, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.sharedFunction()}
      </div>;
  }
}
```

When using `Component` class you can take advantage of it's two generic arguments, first one defined the interface of props and the second one defines interface of the state. You can either use `SharedFeature` interface directly or extend another interface by it and then use that interface for props.

I dont know what kind of IDE you use but usually in this case when you do "Go to implementation" the IDE should succesfuly locate class `Parent` as it `implements` the interface that defines the function `sharedFunction()`;

Beware that if you do "Go to definition" you WILL be taken to the declaration of the interface `SharedFeature`. If you want to use "Go to definition" nontheless (antipattern)use the class `Parent` itself as type for class `Child`'s props. However this also makes `Parent`'s method `render()` and ANY OTHER MEMBERS part of the props aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work the way you are hoping it will. Namely your `<Child/>` component shouldn't have any awareness as to what passed it the `simplifiedFunction` prop. In your case, you happen to be passing it in from `<Parent/>`, but you should be able to pass in any function that satisfies the contract of the function. Imagine you had 3 other components that passed in different functions, your child component should never have to care about that.

Comment: The question is about IDE's TypeScriptu intellisense not about actual runtime ownership of the disputed method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says that you *"want to tell Typescript that one member of one of my class is coming from another class."* This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), in the sense that you say you want to do one thing (copy a method from one class to another) but your goal is something else (passing a method to a React component), and this should be done a different way.

[Luk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012533/12299000) gives a good solution for your actual use case. In my answer I'll address the original question about copying a method from one class to another, and explain why doing that is not a good solution.

---

Strictly speaking, the answer is simple:

```js
class Main {
    foo(): void {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}

class Child {
    foo = Main.prototype.foo;
}
```

However, **do not do this**. You will be arrested by the OOP police, and sent to OOP jail.

It almost always doesn't make sense to do this. A method on the class `Main` may make use of properties that are defined in that class. `Child` is not a subclass of `Main` so it does not necessarily have the same properties. What if it's like this?

```js
class Main {
    x: string = 'bar';

    foo(): void {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}

class Child {
    foo = Main.prototype.foo;
}
```

Now what is `new Child().foo()` supposed to do? A `Child` has no `x` property to log.

If the `foo` method really doesn't access any of `Main`'s properties, and this fact is part of `Main`'s contract (as depended on in the `Child` class), then the method should be `static` and the `Child` class should invoke it as `Main.foo()`.

If the `foo` method *does* access some of `Main`'s properties, but only properties shared by the `Child` class, then you should design your class hierarchy so that either `Child` is a subclass of `Main`, or so that those properties and the `foo` method belong to a common superclass, so that they can be shared by inheritance.

Comment: I think that you missed the whole React part that includes using props to share the function to a child component. It's a way how event handlers are constructed and used.

Comment: I answered the question, which was *"I want to tell Typescript that one member of one of my class is coming from another class"*. The part about React is under "Use Case", explaining the motivation for the question. It is an "XY problem", and my answer addresses the X part. Your answer (which I upvoted) gives the answer to the Y part. http://xyproblem.info/ I will edit to make this clear.